# Error encountered with POST request to Botify

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send a `POST` response to `Botify` and receive response as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://developers.botify.com/docs/export-job-reference). However, the job keeps on failing. I haven't used Botify before so requesting help in fixing the failure :

**Python program**:

```
import requests
import json

token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

url = "https://api.botify.com/v1/jobs"

json = {
  "job_type": "export",
  "payload": {
    "username": "XYZ0",
    "project": "XYZ.com",
    "export_size": 50,
    "formatter": "csv",
    "formatter_config": {
            "delimiter": ",",
            "print_delimiter": False,
            "print_header": True,
            "header_format": "verbose"
        },
    "connector": "direct_download",
    "extra_config": {},
    "query": {
      "collections": ["crawl.20230509"],
      "query": {
        "dimensions": ["url",
                       "crawl.20230509.date_crawled",
                       "crawl.20230509.content_type",
                       "crawl.20230509.http_code"
                       ],
        "metrics": [],
        "sort": [1]
      }
    }
  }
}

headers = {
    # "accept": "application/json",

    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Token {token}"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=json, headers=headers).json()

print(response)
```

Note: I'm unsure as to what to put in the `extra_config` element above, so I passed an empty dictionary.

**Error**:

```
{'status': 400, 'error': {'error_code': '1020', 'message': 'Badly formatted request', 'error_detail': {'payload': {'query': {'collections': ['Unknown collection "crawl.20230509".']}}}}}
```

**EDIT**:-
The following code is a different sample code very similar which works. Not sure where I am going wrong in my version:

```
url = "https://api.botify.com/v1/jobs"

token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

headers = {
    #"accept": "application/json",
    
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Token {token}"    
}

data = """
{
  "job_type": "export",
  "payload": {
    "username": "XXXX0",
    "project": "XXXXX.com",
    "connector": "direct_download",
    "formatter": "csv",
    "formatter_config": {
            "delimiter": ",",
            "print_delimiter": false,
            "print_header": true,
            "header_format": "verbose"
        },
    "export_size": 50,
    "query": {
      "collections": ["crawl.20250515"],
      "query": {
        "dimensions": ["url",
"crawl.20221012.date_crawled",
"crawl.20221012.content_type",
"crawl.20221012.http_code"
],
        "metrics": [],
        "sort": [1]
      }
```

Can someone please help me fix the issue.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What does the query as described [here](https://developers.botify.com/docs/collections-and-periods#query) return? Does it contain `crawl.20230509`?

Comment: I tried with the following: curl --request POST --url https://api.botify.com/v1/projects/XXXX/XXXX.com/collections --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' but it still errors - 
curl --request POST --url https://api.botify.com/v1/projects/easyjet0/easyjet.com/collections --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: 82adaeb6ec986033975a105cedd11fb8742af1f1' .. So where should i pass my credentials in the POST request ? Shouldn't mentioning the Token in the `curl` command suffice ?

Comment: I have edited my question. Pls take a look. The 2nd program works but my version as given above doesn't. Not sure where I may be going wrong

Comment: The request you posted in your edit uses a different collection (`crawl.20250515` instead of `crawl.20230509`)

Comment: yes I tried with that too... No luck

Comment: Oh sorry i was confused because you said `The following code works`. Could you please rephrase that

Comment: Anyway you probably don't have a crawl on 2025-05-15 either. Maybe try `crawl.20230515`

Comment: thank you for reply. I am sorry for the confusion. The code indicated at the end of the question is a sample script that works fine with the same Token Id. My version is the one mentioned in the beginning of the question. I was trying to compare both since my version is not working